# How to fix permission denied error when trying to install packages using Ansible?

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I'm trying to write a simple Ansible Playbook, please look at snippets below. Using Ansible 2.4.0.0, Ubuntu 17.04, Python 2.7.13.
This is my first time using Ansible and Playbooks so please don't be too harsh. What am I doing wrong?

playbook.yml

```
---
- name: install packages
  hosts: dbservers
  become: yes
  become_method: sudo
  become_user: user

  tasks:
  - name: Update repositories cache and install "python-minimal" package
  apt:
    name: python-minimal
    update_cache: yes
```

hosts file

```
 ---
 [dbservers]
 db ansible_host=127.0.0.1 ansible_port=22 ansible_user=user ansible_ssh_pass=pass ansible_become_pass=pass ansible_become_user=user
```

Command: `ansible-playbook -i hosts playbook.yml -vvv`

Command above returns following error:

```
The full traceback is:
  File "/tmp/ansible_yozgsn/ansible_module_apt.py", line 287, in <module>
    import apt

fatal: [db]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": false, 
    "cmd": "apt-get update", 
    "failed": true, 
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "allow_unauthenticated": false, 
            "autoclean": false, 
            "autoremove": false, 
            "cache_valid_time": 0, 
            "deb": null, 
            "default_release": null, 
            "dpkg_options": "force-confdef,force-confold", 
            "force": false, 
            "force_apt_get": false, 
            "install_recommends": null, 
            "name": "python-minimal", 
            "only_upgrade": false, 
            "package": [
                "python-minimal"
            ], 
            "purge": false, 
            "state": "present", 
            "update_cache": true, 
            "upgrade": null
        }
    }, 
    "msg": "W: chmod 0700 of directory /var/lib/apt/lists/partial failed - SetupAPTPartialDirectory (1: Operation not permitted)\nE: Could not open lock file /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (13: Permission denied)\nE: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/\nW: Problem unlinking the file /var/cache/apt/pkgcache.bin - RemoveCaches (13: Permission denied)\nW: Problem unlinking the file /var/cache/apt/srcpkgcache.bin - RemoveCaches (13: Permission denied)", 
    "rc": 100, 
    "stderr": "W: chmod 0700 of directory /var/lib/apt/lists/partial failed - SetupAPTPartialDirectory (1: Operation not permitted)\nE: Could not open lock file /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (13: Permission denied)\nE: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/\nW: Problem unlinking the file /var/cache/apt/pkgcache.bin - RemoveCaches (13: Permission denied)\nW: Problem unlinking the file /var/cache/apt/srcpkgcache.bin - RemoveCaches (13: Permission denied)\n", 
    "stderr_lines": [
        "W: chmod 0700 of directory /var/lib/apt/lists/partial failed - SetupAPTPartialDirectory (1: Operation not permitted)", 
        "E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (13: Permission denied)", 
        "E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/", 
        "W: Problem unlinking the file /var/cache/apt/pkgcache.bin - RemoveCaches (13: Permission denied)", 
        "W: Problem unlinking the file /var/cache/apt/srcpkgcache.bin - RemoveCaches (13: Permission denied)"
    ], 
    "stdout": "Reading package lists...\n", 
    "stdout_lines": [
        "Reading package lists..."
    ]
}
```

Edit: If I connect through SSH to the same machine I can manually update apt-cache and install packages using same user (using sudo). If I run command 'whoami' inside Playbook it returns expected result (user name).

Comment: [Please read](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) the [guide to asking questions on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). You responded to each of these answers once, but apparently when you got your answer never came back and accepted one or answered outstanding questions to you (though you did edit as asked).

Answer (score 7):

If your user has sudo access, use `become:` -

```
tasks:
  - name: Update repositories cache and install "python-minimal" package
    become: yes
    apt:
      name: python-minimal
      update_cache: yes
```

Comment: If I use become: - then I get syntax error. I also tried to remove all become variables from both playbook and hosts (used in CLI) but it did not help.

Answer (score 7):

I think you're confusing `become_user` and `remote_user`.  `remote_user` is the user Ansible will use to ssh to the server and `become_user` is the user Ansible will switch to and run tasks while on the server.  You can find out more about `become_user` and `remote_user` inside [Ansible's docs](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/become.html).

So what's happening here is your playbook is trying to become the "user" user and install packages.  It's not installing the packages as root which is what you need.  To fix this you can either remove the `become_user` param from your playbook (`become_user` defaults as root) or you can add a `become_user` param to your task.

```
- name: Update repositories cache and install "python-minimal" package
  apt:
    name: python-minimal
    update_cache: yes
  become_user: root
```

Comment: I don't have access to root user, I have sudoers user account. Is this the root of my problem? (no pun intended) :)

Comment: if you `sudo -l`, what commands do you have permission to run? I hope we don't have to tweak the ansible.cfg

Comment: You need to install packages as root.  You might already have the access to do this - I'm not sure what sudoers user account means.  `sudo -l` will tell us if you can or not.